# Validating values in YAML files across collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, yaml

I'm using Node (https://eemeli.org/yaml/) to parse a YAML configuration files which looks like so:

```
items:
  - name: item 1
    value: 25
  - name: item 2
    value: 25
  - name: item 3
    value: 50
```

What I'd like to do is assert the `value` numbers all add up to 100 when parsing the document.

Should I be running this validation after parsing the YAML

eg:

```
data = YAML.parse(recipe)
validate(data)
```

Or is there a better way of doing this using the YAML library directly when loading the document?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have to parse it first as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better of parsing the YAML first, then going through the resulting data. So, in this case, the parsed data would look something like:

```js
data = {
    items: [
        {name: 'item 1', value: 25},
        {name: 'item 2', value: 25},
        ...
    ]
}
```

So, you can just loop through the values:

```js
let total = 0;

data.items.map((item) => {
    total += item.value;
});

if (total !== 100) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would probably be the case!